# Android Studio - Java - TelephonyManager - error: non-static method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telephonymanager

How can i solve the this problem?
I don't see System.out.println
I want to see System.out.println ethe of in.
I see error in logcat.
My codes are in the external java class.

My codes are here:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class bilgiCek extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void telefonBilgi(){
        TelephonyManager bilgiler = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // Error is here.

        String simUlke = bilgiler.getSimCountryIso();
        String netUlke = bilgiler.getNetworkCountryIso();
        String imei = bilgiler.getImei();
        String simNo = bilgiler.getSimSerialNumber();
        String sesMail = bilgiler.getVoiceMailNumber();
        System.out.println("İmei Numarası" + imei);
    }

}
```

Error outpu are here:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\90505\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\test\smsOkuma.java:16: error: non-static method getSystemService(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
        TelephonyManager bilgiler = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                                                       ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
```

Comment: Add this as a comment.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the non-stati context as parameter as below

```
  public static void telefonBilgi(Context context){
    TelephonyManager bilgiler = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String simUlke = bilgiler.getSimCountryIso();
    String netUlke = bilgiler.getNetworkCountryIso();
    String imei = bilgiler.getImei();
    String simNo = bilgiler.getSimSerialNumber();
    String sesMail = bilgiler.getVoiceMailNumber();
    System.out.println("İmei Numarası" + imei);
}
```

This might work